# Trying to join tables in astropy but getting argument error

Tags: python, join, key, astropy

I have three tables, sersic, mass, and magphys. Each are pretty significantly large tables, and I'm looking to join them into one, using the ID (CATAID) as a reference. However, when I use the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import ascii
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kstest
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
from scipy.stats import anderson
from scipy.stats import anderson_ksamp


import pandas as pd
from astropy.table import Table, join
import urllib.request
```

to import all of my info, then downloading and naming my individual tables from the files:

```
sersic = Table.read('Sersic.fits', format='fits')
mass = Table.read('StellarMass.fits', format='fits')
magphys = Table.read('MagPhys.fits', format='fits')
```

then trying to form the fourth, joined table using the CATAID column (first in each table, dtype int32):

```
gama = join(sersic, mass, magphys, keys='CATAID')
```

I'm getting an error that says

```
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c200aeac718e> in <module>
----> 1 gama = join(sersic, mass, magphys, keys='CATAID')

TypeError: join() got multiple values for argument 'keys'.
```

How can I fix this multiple argument error and form the single table, titled 'gama'?

if I can't join all three tables into one, how do I at least join two, such as sersic and mass?

Answer (score 2):

The Table `join` method requires exactly two tables as the first two arguments, a left and right table to join.  Please see https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html#join for examples and information about how to call `join`.

You can join three tables by joining the first two, and then joining that result to the third table.

The error you are seeing is because `keys` is the third argument to join, so it thinks you are providing `keys` twice.